# Retrieving a number through JSON Data

Tags: java, android, json, android-layout, android-activity

I have an activity that retrieves JSON data on android, and later stores it in Parse.
I am able to retrieve an item and classify it as string such as:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String list_item;
list_item_price = i.getStringExtra("list_item");
```

My issue that I would like to classify as number such as
Number list_item, however, I can't figure out how to initialize it as a number.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: with number do you mean int?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean

Comment: OK could you add the JSON data or the list_item in the question?

Answer (score 1):

**Sending integer value from FirstActivity to SecondActivity**

//FirstActivity

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("KeyName",INTEGER_VALUE);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

//SecondActivity

```
  Intent i = getIntent();
  int var = i.getIntExtra("KeyName", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this

[`public int getIntExtra (String name, int defaultValue)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getIntExtra(java.lang.String,%20int))

also look at [`public Intent putExtra (String name, int value)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20int)).

Answer (score 0):

might you need something like this:

```
int i=0;
Intent in = getIntent();
i = Integer.parseInt(in.getStringExtra("list_item"));
```